# How can I display my buttons and imageview with the same size as in androidstudio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I tried to solve this issue for almost 4 hours. Also in my previous application, I had the same problem. I created a background on canva.com that has 720X1280 . and I am designing in android studio with the same resolution. Also, I am using emulator which has a 720x1280 screen size. However, my app looks like this.
I also tried to add this photo(background) as `imageview`. How can I display my app properly in different devices even though they have different resolution. This is my grand problem in designing.
Thanks in advance

**This is how my app appears on the emulator**

[image: This is how my app appears on the emulator]

**Here is my XML code**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bck2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonlog"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonreg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please refer https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bck2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonlog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yourfilenamefor button1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonreg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/yourfilenamefor button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the xml file you need to change

1.You need to create a new xml file in the drawable folder which will be linked to your button 1 file and same you will do for button 2.

2.After that the background you created "bck2" from that you can remove button images because you have already created button images in step 1.

3.Now if u want your app that it should support all screen size then you have to give the proper alingment for that you can use "layout_margin,align,padding and more for more you can refer to this link
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: For your screen size you can use SP for text size and DP for everything else.